# How to initialize a vector of user defined objects in class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to initialize a vector of user defined struct object in the class constructor . How can I do that in C++11 or above?

I have the following struct inside my `CPUsageTracker` class:

```cpp
typedef struct cpu_info
  {
    std::string cpu_label;
    size_t cpu_time_array[static_cast<uint8_t>(CpuTimeState::CPU_TIME_STATES_NUM)];
  } cpu_info_obj;
```

I now declare a `std::vector` of the struct objects as one of the data members of the class:

```cpp
std::vector<CPUsageTracker::cpu_info> m_entries;
```

How can I initialize this vector in my `CPUsageTracker` constructor?

```cpp
CPUsageTracker()
  : m_cpu_cores(0U),
    m_cpu_total_time(0),
    m_cpu_load(0.0) {}
```

Comment: What do you want to initialize it to? What have you tried?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can just initialize it with a defined size with an empty struct obj? Like this:

```m_entries(static_cast<uint8_t>(CpuTimeState::CPU_TIME_STATES_NUM),cpu_info()) 
```

Comment: @DivyaAggarwal This should work. Have you tried it? (You could even remove the second argument completely.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay let me try compiling this. Will remove and try second argument and try to. Thanks

Comment: Something like that yes. [This `std::vector` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) might be useful. Also note that you probably don't need that `static_cast`, depending on what `CpuTimeState` and `CpuTimeState::CPU_TIME_STATES_NUM` is.

Comment: Great thanks all. This instantiation worked :```m_entries(static_cast<uint8_t(CpuTimeState::CPU_TIME_STATES_NUM))```  @Someprogrammerdude Yeah the `static_cast` is just for safety